# Input array is longer than the number of columns

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, vb.net-2010

In the event dragdrop of a datagridview I got this error:

[image]

Here's the whole code of my dragdrop event :

```
    Private Sub DataGridView1_DragDrop(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.DragDrop

    Dim clientPoint As Point = DataGridView1.PointToClient(New Point(e.X, e.Y))
    Dim hit As DataGridView.HitTestInfo = DataGridView1.HitTest(clientPoint.X, clientPoint.Y)

    Dim dgvr As DataGridViewRow = DirectCast(e.Data.GetData(GetType(DataGridViewRow)), DataGridViewRow)
    Dim celldata As Object() = New Object(dgvr.Cells.Count) {}
    For col As Integer = 0 To dgvr.Cells.Count - 1
        celldata(col) = dgvr.Cells(col).Value
    Next


    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    dt = ds_data.Tables(0)
    Dim colCheckbox As DataColumn = dt.Columns.Add("Column1", GetType(Boolean))
    Dim row As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
    row.ItemArray = celldata
    dt.Rows.InsertAt(row, hit.RowIndex)

    dgvr.DataGridView.Rows.Remove(dgvr)
    Dim sqlCmd As SqlCommand
    sqlCmd = con.CreateCommand()
    sqlCmd.CommandText = "update megatom_data_commande set ordre='" & hit.RowIndex & "' where id='" & DataGridView1.Rows(hit.RowIndex).Cells("ID").Value.ToString & "'"

    Try

        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        DataGridView2.DataSource = ds_data2.Tables(0).DefaultView
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds_data.Tables(0).DefaultView
        Dim CMD As New SqlCommand("PLANNIFIER")
        CMD.Parameters.Add("@CHAINE", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cboChaine.SelectedItem.ToString

        ExecuteCMD(CMD)

    Catch ex As SqlException
    End Try
End Sub
```

In fact my datatable have 15 columns but I added manually a checkbox column to select rows so I think i have a problem of indexes but I dont know how to resolve that problem.

My ds_data is defined like the code below:

```
   requestPlanifie = "select megatom_data_commande.id as ID,numéro,observation,moule,commande,id_etat,programme,ordre,moule,glav,Qté_commandée_Totale," _
       & " Qté_coupée_cuir, Qté_coupée_synthétique, Qté_piquée, Qté_finie from megatom_data_commande" _
& " inner join dbo.MEGATOM_DATA_MOULE on megatom_data_moule.id=megatom_data_commande.id_moule " _
& " where id_chaine='" & cboChaine.Text & "' and ( id_etat='3' or id_etat='4') order by numéro asc,ordre asc"
        Dim dataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter(requestPlanifie, con)
         Try

            dataAdapter.Fill(ds_data, "ds_data")
            dataAdapter2.Fill(ds_data2, "ds_data2")
        Catch ex As SqlException


        End Try
       DataGridView1.DataSource = ds_data.Tables(0).DefaultView
```

Comment: How is ds_data defined?

Comment: Please post your code, not a picture of your code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I just edited my question and added some code.

Comment: since the drag source and drag drop DGVs apparently have different column counts, `celldata ` should be the size of the DEST DGV columns count.  Then rather than copying all columns, only copy when (meaningful) names match or map them.

Comment: also, by dragging a row of cells, you **might** be mixing up the order.  If the user changed the column display order, the dgvr.Cells might be in that order rather than the actual DGV.Columns order, so FirstName might get pasted to the LastName column.  It would be easy to see in Debug whether the order is Column Index or Column DisplayIndex to know if that is an issue.

Comment: @Plutonix yes exactly i must be mixing orders.In fact I edited my code by add a datacolumn for my checkbox and I got same order